# "Height=100%" is not working in html when using <!DOCTYPE>?

Tags: html

When I use HTML without `DOCTYPE`, my HTML page `Height=100%` is working.

But when I use `DOCTYPE`, height is not working correctly...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="11" height ="100%">
    <tr>
        <td height="100%" bgcolor="#008000">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Here's a simple and clear explanation of the DOCTYPE issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276

Answer (score 54):

Adding a `DOCTYPE` switches you from [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) to standards mode. In standards mode, the `html` and `body` elements do not default to 100% of the size of the viewport (browser window); instead, they are only as large as they need to be to contain their children. The `table` height of 100% means 100% of the containing element, but that's only as large as it needs to be to contain the contents of the table. Quirks mode is an emulation of the behavior of older browsers, in which the `html` and `body` elements filled the viewport.

To fix the problem, you just need to add this to your document:

```
<style>
  html, body { height: 100% }
</style>
```

Comment: i try like above , but width(100%) is working but height not working

Comment: Can you edit your post with the exact code that you are trying, and which browser(s) it fails on?

Comment: I tested this in Firefox, and result is Okay. thanks @Brian Campbell

Comment: I just read this 11 years old answer and it put me on the right track to solve my very frustrating problem. I needed to add "height: 100%" to some <div> css classes too. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When you state 'height=100%' you have to think "100% of what?". It's the parent of that table element which is the body. But how tall is the body?

To do what you want, add this in the CSS:
html,body{height:100%}

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said the main part of the solution is to put

`html, body{'height=100%'}`

But its also really important to set every single ancestor's height to be 100%. for example if your code is as follows

```
<body>
    <div id="firstdiv">
         <div id="scnddiv">
               lets say this is the div you want to make 100%
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

if #scnddiv is the div you want to make 100%, not only you have to make html and body 100% but also #firstdiv. So it will look something like this

```
html, body, #firstdiv {height:100%}
```

then you can make anything in that div to be 100%.

I hope this helps.