# Why does <!DOCTYPE html> break height: 100%?

Tags: css, html

This code works:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>#a { height: 100%; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form>
     <textarea id="a"></textarea>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and produces a 100% height textarea.

If we add `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top, it doesn't work anymore (the height isn't 100% anymore).

**Why?** According to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp), it seems that adding this DOCTYPE is making it HTML5. Why would HTML5 break the `height: 100%;`?

Comment: height:100% is relative to parent element, and nothing is specified on the parent element (form)

Comment: Why does it work without doctype then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Height=100%" is not working in html when using <!DOCTYPE>, How i can fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966300/height-100-is-not-working-in-html-when-using-doctype-how-i-can-fix-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use of `<!DOCTYPE html>`,you are in `standard mode` and `html` and `body` have `height` equal his inside content,so you must use this code:

```
html, body, form, #a {
   height:100%;
}
```

but when you don't use of `DOCTYPE` you are in  `quirks mode` and , `html` and `body` have default `height` equal `100%`,only use this code:

```
#a {
   height:100%;
}
```